# PHP Loading Blank Page

Tags: php, logging

I recently moved my website from one server to another.  My index.php file uses the smarty template system to load multiple pages based on the URL.  However, one specific page is loading blank now.

I don't necessarily need help **fixing** any coding issue, I need help **finding** the error.

There's no PHP error that displays and the server doesn't give a 403, 404, 500, or any other error response that I can see.  Can anyone offer suggestions on how to find what's causing the error?

Perhaps adding something to the PHP file to display every error or searching the server logs to see what's causing the error to occur.  As of right now, I can't necessarily narrow it down to a specific file, much less a specific line.  Any suggestions on what I should add or where I should look?

I'm open to adding whatever to the PHP file to trace the error, using command-line/shell to locate log files, using Perl to track down the error, and so on.  Anything will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**  This is on a Linux/CentOS servers that's running cPanel/WHM.

**EDIT 2:**  After following Tim's advice below, it appears that the error is coming from this line:

```
$app->map('/panel/ajax', $auth('member'), function () use ($app) {
```

Here's the line in a bit more context:

```
  $app->flash('restore_panel_filters', '1');
  $app->redirect($redirect);
})->via('GET','POST');
$app->map('/panel/ajax', $auth('member'), function () use ($app) {
  $req = $app->request();
  $user_id = $app->view()->getData('user_id');
```

Any idea what would be causing this to happen?

Comment: turn on error reporting (turn it off after fixing). Either by server config or add this to the beginning of your script "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);"

Comment: have you turned on error reporting? Add this to the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: If no errors how - When this happens to me i just `die('hello')` through the script, starting at the top and, when I don't see the message anymore i've found the problem.

Comment: @Tim hopefully you use xdebug while developing locally, if not then go check it out. It's a lifesaver.

Comment: @JimL I don't, but I'll look into it. I use a class on a server that gives zero indication that it's failing - no error logs, nothing, just a blank white page. The only way I could find it was by using `die()` block by block...

Comment: Updated original question based off Tim's suggestion.

Comment: Is there any specific PHP library or extension needed for mapping URLs?  Perhaps I just forgot to install something when moving servers...